# Simulating click via Android Accessibility Service

Tags: java, android

I am trying to simulate a click function in an android application utilizing the Accessability Service. I have set up the service in the manifest, and enabled it in my phones settings. I have a class MouseAccessabilityService which contains a the following click function:

```
// Clikc function that clicks at a specific x and y coordinate
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static GestureDescription click(float x, float y) {
    // for a single tap a duration of 1 ms is enough
    final int DURATION = 1;

    Path clickPath = new Path();
    clickPath.moveTo(x, y);
    GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke =
            new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, DURATION);
    GestureDescription.Builder clickBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
    clickBuilder.addStroke(clickStroke);
    return clickBuilder.build();
}
```

I am calling the click function in the MainActivity via a button press that triggers the click (for testing purposes):

```
Buttonclick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);

    Buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //changeButtonText.setText("Second Text");
            MouseAccessabilityService.click(centerX, centerY);
        }
    });
```

The X and Y is being passed as an integer variable from some other functionality. I can not seem to get the click() function to work from within my app and press on a button.

Am I on the right page? Can this functionality even work? I am at a standstill with this and would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dispatchGesture function.

Try replacing your click function's return with :
`return dispatchGesture(clickBuilder.build(), null, null);`

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/#7